# Installation issue my urls wont work in Drupal 8 install

Tags: drupal, installation

I installed drupal 8 on my localhost. Installation went fine got the db installed correctly but when I try using any links I get this error. Not Found
The requested URL /drupal/admin/content was not found on this server. Also the css is broken. I think I will try a fresh install see if I have same issue.

Comment: I found this link I should be able to fix this. Thanks my friend https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/clean-urls-in-drupal-8/fix-drupal-8-clean-urls-problems

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable clean URLs. Otherwise you will get the link by http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/content